# Move the next view programmatically when using popup view(iOS,swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3

I usely using this code when I want move the UIVeiw programmatically.

```
let customVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextUIViewController") as! NextUIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(reservationsVC, animated: true)
```

I used pop-ups to get information to the user.(I using tapView and navigation controller too.) I developed the alert to appear when I press the OK button included in the pop-up. I wanted to be able to click on the alert's OK button to move the view. but in this case, my code doen't work.

I guess it will not be an alert issue because I used alert before. Anyone know about this problem or diffrent way to move the UIView programmatically?

this is my whole codes(pop-up)

```
import UIKit
class ReservationPopupViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func closePopup(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func SelectTerm(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

@IBAction func selectNumberOfPeople(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

@IBAction func selectNumberOfChild(_ sender: UIButton) {
}



@IBAction func registReservation(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    _ = SweetAlert().showAlert("Success", subTitle: "You did reservation", style: AlertStyle.success, buttonTitle:"OK") { (isOtherButton) -> Void in
        if isOtherButton == true {

            print("==== Clicked reservation ====")
            // move next page
            let reservationsVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "reservationsController") as! ReservationsController

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(reservationsVC, animated: true)

            print("==== Clicked reservation END====")

        }
    }

}

}
```

"==== Clicked reservation ====" and "==== Clicked reservation END====" are output successfully.

Comment: make sure that self.navigationController is not nil. I think the code is not getting navigation controller's reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed popup code and I solve the problem.. And I already don't know why my code didn't work that case.